# CSS file and User control references

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm currently building from scratch an ASP.NET with C# website, using Visual Studio. I have an aspx file that references a couple of user controls (ascx) like this:

```
<%@ Register src="UserControls/CategoriesList.ascx" tagname="CategoriesList" tagprefix="uc2" %>
```

I am interested in customizing some elements on the page (e.g. labels, etc), so I included (immediately after the above line) a reference to my .CSS file:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Cinemax.css" />
```

After doing so, I got an error message:

> Parser Error Message: Only Content controls are allowed directly in a
>   content page that contains Content controls.

The error specifically points to the `<link rel.... (line of code inserted above.)`

Is there a workaround so I can include [in the same file!] references to user controls, as well as to a CSS stylesheet? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose that you should put the line including *css* to the file in `<head></head>` section of the page.

Comment: Excellent, thank you, Lucas, that was the solution! 
 In fact, since I didn't find any body or head tag in this file, I went back to the master page and added the CSS reference there. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Indeed, Nikhil, I am using a master page, why do you ask?

Comment: I'm glad it helped :). I'll add this as an answer, but I haven't finished writing it yet :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you should put the line including *css* to the file in `<head></head>` section of the page, so your file can look like this:

```
<%@ Register src="UserControls/CategoriesList.ascx" tagname="CategoriesList" tagprefix="uc2" %>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Cinemax.css" />
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

**Update:** You wrote you use **master page**, so putting it in the `head` section there should solve the issue. It worked for you, so I'm writing it, so it can also be helpful for the other people who have a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are using a master page. Master page has

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder
```

tags. Your page in question overrides content of these tags by using

```
<asp:Content
```

tags.

By default, your master page should have something like this (a reference to the head section of the page):

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
```

To reference you stylesheet from the page you are talking about, you would do this:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Cinemax.css" />
</asp:Content>
```

because css references must reside in the head section. And as for the error you are getting, this is because if a page has a master page, it cannon have any content outside of the

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder
```

tags.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a master page and you do not have place all the content inside `<asp:Content` controls, and so you get this message.

Ensure that all your content is inside content controls that come from master page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to `<asp:Content />` tags, you can't put anything outside of them in
 an .aspx page. So you're limited to putting them inside the  tag.

If you want `<script />` and `<link />` tags you need to either put a `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder />` in the `<head>` of your master page, or add them dynamically via the Page's `Controls` collection.

Comment: There was an issue with text formatting in your answer and all the text looked like a source code, so I fixed it. I suppose an extra `ContentPlaceHolder` in not needed in this case, because just one *css* for all the pages defined directly in master page is satisfying. Anyway, it's a worth noticing that this can also be done with a `ContentPlaceHolder` :).